# VBA EXCEL - NUMBERFORMAT didn´t work but FORMAT FUNCTION did

Tags: excel, vba, format, number-formatting

I have a range of cells named MyCells as string type. In which there are strings with 26 digits.

Why the first statement (below), with NumberFormat didn´t work, but the second did?

Trying cells look like this:

38935094000163001000052234 --> 38.935.094/0001-63   001   000052234

First attempt (didn´t work):

```
range(MyCells).Select

Selection.NumberFormat = "00"".""000"".""000""/""0000""-""00""   ""000""   ""000000000"
```

Second (successful):

```
range(MyCells).Select

For Each c In Selection
    c = Format(c, "00"".""000"".""000""/""0000""-""00""   ""000""   ""000000000")
Next
```

Comment: You are really looking for what is known as a character or text mask. The VBA.Strings.Format function can handle them, but Excel Number Format (or the TEXT formula function) cannot. You can workaround it either like you did, or through creating a UDF you can call from a worksheet formula that simply passes in your arguments to the VBA Format function, or through normal non-VBA formulae that splits the string and adds stuff (like e.g. `=LEFT(x,4)&"-"&MID(x,5,3)&"-"&MID(x,8,2)` and so on and so forth).

Comment: Thanks, Cor_Blimey. I still have some confusion about cells type and cells mask. Searching about, I think that the only three types (returned from TypeName funciont) of a cell are string, double and date, doesn´t matter what kind of "type" or mask we set in the worksheet, like currency, percent or number. Is this correct?

Comment: boolean also. But yeah otherwise I think you're right. Either way, cell number format doesn't change the data type, and special formatting like what you posted (e.g. "#.0") will not be applied to text. If pnuts' answered helped mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

"The Format function uses different format code strings than do the NumberFormat and NumberFormatLocal properties." from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224873%28v=office.11%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Excel only keeps the first 15 digits of numbers.  That number you put up is 26 digits and the only way Excel would keep the numbers after the first 15 digits would be if it was stored as a text.  As a result, number formats won't work on it because Excel sees it as a text string, not a number.

Comment: So NUMBERFORMAT only works with numbers? Can´t I use a string as argument of NUMBERFORMAT?

Comment: See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx) for custom cell formatting details